# Converting LINQ to .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, linq, c#-2.0

How should I use this in .NET 2.0 ...?

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public IEnumerable<OperatorField> FindByType(String type)
{
    //  return only selected type
    return (from ce in this.OperatorFields where ce.Type == type select ce).ToList();
}
```

I use this in a 3.5 projects, but now I'm adding new functionality to an old project that I cannot (at this time) upgrade to 3.5.

---

I just did this:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public IEnumerable<OperatorField> FindByType(String type)
{
    //  return only selected type
    //return (from ce in this.OperatorFields where ce.Type == type select ce).ToList();

    List<OperatorField> r = new List<OperatorField>();

    foreach (OperatorField f in this.OperatorFields)
        if (f.Type == type)
            r.Add(f);

    return r;
}
```

Comment: If you take a look at the IL, is there really any difference? Can you measure the perf of both and see if one or the other is faster?

Comment: 2 min and 4 identical answers :)

Comment: @StingyJack: The IL won't be at all similar, because the linq version will have calls to `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where()`, `System.Linq.Enumerable.Select()`, and `System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList()`, while the other version will call `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` and iterate over the result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you still use C# 3.0 but not .NET 3.5? If so, keep the code as it is and use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), which is LINQ to Objects implemented for .NET 2.0.

Otherwise, do this:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public IEnumerable<OperatorField> FindByType(String type)
{
    List<OperatorField> list = new List<OperatorField>();
    foreach (OperatorField ce in OperatorFields)
    {
        if (ce.Type == type)
        {
            list.Add(ce);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: 2.0 only :( at least until the next version so we can tell clients that they need to upgrade the framework.  I just add what I think, a solution.

Comment: @balexandre: No, you mistake me. You can use Visual Studio 2008 and C# 3.0 features but still target .NET 2.0. You don't need your clients to upgrade the framework for that to work.

Comment: @balexandre: are you developing in VS 2008 or 2005? Jon's suggestion with LINQBridge actually makes it possible for you to run LINQ on .Net 2.0... But with a C#3 compiler that comes with VS2k8. So if you're developing in VS2k8, you can easily keep the code and add the assembly. It will work flawlessly on .net 2.0

Comment: In that case you can use C# 3 - lambda expressions, query expressions etc. Use LINQBridge and you can keep the original code.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain what you don't like about this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps?

```
IList<OperatorField> col = new List<OperatorField>();
foreach (OperatorField f in this.OperatorFields)
{
    if (f.Type == type)
        col.Add(f);
}
return col;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
public IEnumerable<OperatorField> FindByType(String type)
{
    foreach (OperatorField ce in this.OperatorFields)
    {
        if (ce.Type == type)
            yield return ce;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about what the statement is doing, it's iterating over each item in the OperatorFields property, checking the type and then adding the item to a list before returning the completed list.

So you've got

```
Create new list
For each item in OperatorFields
  if item.Type equals type
    add item to list

return list
```